# How to modify tensor values based on a condition

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following line of code would work in numpy but is not working in tensorflow:

```
class_max[class_max == 1] *= class_weights[0]
```

The error is as following:

ValueError: mask cannot be scalar.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where):

```
tf.where(
  class_max == 1,
  class_max * class_weights[0],
  class_max
)
```